# Why is the Rust libstd linked dynamically without using -C prefer-dynamic flag after compiling a dynamic library?

Tags: rust, dynamic-linking, linkage, rust-cargo

I am having an issue understanding how Cargo links binaries when building a dynamic library. To understand it better, I took the [coreutils project](https://github.com/uutils/coreutils) and tried to build 'ls' changing Cargo.toml and other stuff to make the executable as small as possible. I rapidly found out that linking libraries dynamically could reduce the size of the executables drastically.

Digging through the internet for optimizations, I found that when you generate libraries as "dylibs" in Cargo, they still include "libstd" statically unless you explicitly tell the compiler to include it dynamically using the flag "-C prefer-dynamic".

I don't use the flag, but still end up having libstd linked dynamically, which is very strange.

## Cargo.toml for ls

I modified this a bit.

```
[package]
name = "ls"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = ["Jeremiah Peschka <jeremiah.peschka@gmail.com>"]



[lib]
crate-type=["dylib"]
name = "uu_ls"
path = "ls.rs"

[dependencies]
getopts = "0.2.14"
pretty-bytes = "0.2.1"
term_grid = "0.1.5"
termsize = "0.1.4"
time = "0.1.38"
lazy_static = "0.2.8"
unicode-width = "0.1.4"

[dependencies.uucore]
path = "../uucore"
default-features = false
features = ["entries"]

[[bin]]
name = "ls"
path = "main.rs"
```

## Cargo.toml of uucore

This is the only dependency of ls that I need to compile:

```
[package]
name = "uucore"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = []


[dependencies]
getopts = "0.2.14"
time = { version = "0.1.38", optional = true }
data-encoding = { version = "^1.1", optional = true }

[dependencies.libc]
git = "https://github.com/rust-lang/libc.git"
optional = true

[features]
fs = ["libc"]
utf8 = []
encoding = ["data-encoding"]
parse_time = []
utmpx = ["time", "libc"]
process = ["libc"]
signals = []
entries = ["libc"]
wide = []
utsname = ["libc"]
default = ["fs", "libc", "utf8", "utsname", "encoding", "parse_time", "utmpx", "process", "entries", "signals", "wide"]

[lib]
crate-type=["dylib"]
path = "lib.rs"
name = "uucore"
```

After building the library, I determine whether if it is linked dynamically:

```
ldd ~/target/release/libuu_ls.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd96b98000)
    libuucore.so => not found
    libstd-8eeda694d27cc3ba.so => /home/cibo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-8eeda694d27cc3ba.so (0x00007f86a29d0000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f86a27c8000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f86a25ab000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f86a2394000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f86a1fca000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f86a1cc1000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f86a1abc000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000558ebb132000)
```

As you can see, libstd is dynamically linked here.

Comment: What is exactly your question? Why a dynamic library is linking in things dynamically?

Comment: @Neikos Why the standard library is linked dynamically to the dynamic library ? The documentation says that the standard library should be linked statically unless you specify the flag "-C prefer-dynamic" to the compiler. In this particular case, it links the standard library dynamically whereas when I use dummy projects to test, it works as expected.

Comment: Can you link to the part of the documentation that says that?

Comment: @Neikos https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/3408#issuecomment-279842175 .. This is no the official library but it's the owner of the Cargo project explaining what I am rephrasing here

Comment: @Neikos https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html You can also refer to this page

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/8961616e6004e204327f575081509b049268762b/compiler/rustc_metadata/src/dependency_format.rs, the algorithm for selecting between static and dynamic libraries is:

```
//! 1. If static linking is required, then require all upstream dependencies
//!    to be available as rlibs. If not, generate an error.
//! 2. If static linking is requested (generating an executable), then
//!    attempt to use all upstream dependencies as rlibs. If any are not
//!    found, bail out and continue to step 3.
//! 3. Static linking has failed, at least one library must be dynamically
//!    linked. Apply a heuristic by greedily maximizing the number of
//!    dynamically linked libraries.
//! 4. Each upstream dependency available as a dynamic library is
//!    registered. The dependencies all propagate, adding to a map. It is
//!    possible for a dylib to add a static library as a dependency, but it
//!    is illegal for two dylibs to add the same static library as a
//!    dependency. The same dylib can be added twice. Additionally, it is
//!    illegal to add a static dependency when it was previously found as a
//!    dylib (and vice versa)
//! 5. After all dynamic dependencies have been traversed, re-traverse the
//!    remaining dependencies and add them statically (if they haven't been
//!    added already).
```

According to this algorithm, if not all libraries can be found as static, rustc will automatically prefer dynamic libraries. Furthermore,

```
//! Currently, there is no way to specify the preference of linkage with a
//! particular library (other than a global dynamic/static switch).
```

In your case, it is impossible regardless to link statically against libstd because libuucore.so does not contain libstd. It may be possible on ELF platforms to treat libuucore.so as a "plugin" with symbols satisfied by the main executable, but this is not a standard configuration.